# How to remove BCD from C drive and U drive?

Tags: bcd

I'm trying to remove BCD from my C and U drive and reinstall BCD from scratch on the U drive. Then, I will remove the U drive letter. I can't seem to find a command to delete the BCD from googling. Any help?

[image: Current drive structure]

Comment: Normally the 100 MB System Reserved partition is created, marked as active and contains the boot files (BCD store and BOOTMGR). How did you end up with the BCD store on another partition anyway?